# High resource demanding tasks in websites

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, webserver

I'm newbie in web development and wondering about how to process high resource-demanding task in websites. For example, suppose you have some task that should be done once a day and it requires too much resources and takes a long time on your hosting. Example of such task can getting data from elsewhere, make some calculations on that data, plotting some graphs based on results of calculations and finally inserting results to database. What is the most optimal way of doing such tasks? Does AWS provide solutions for that (for example, rent a computer only for processing your task at a specified time in a day) and if yes, what is the name of that service? I'll be very appreciated by your general advice and options suggestions for me.

Answer (score 0):

For AWS, I'd recommend [AWS Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/what-is-batch.html) for something like this.

From the documentation:

> As a fully managed service, AWS Batch enables developers, scientists,
>   and engineers to run batch computing workloads of any scale. AWS Batch
>   automatically provisions compute resources and optimizes the workload
>   distribution based on the quantity and scale of the workloads. With
>   AWS Batch, there is no need to install or manage batch computing
>   software, which allows you to focus on analyzing results and solving
>   problems. AWS Batch reduces operational complexities, saves time, and
>   reduces costs, which makes it easy for developers, scientists, and
>   engineers to run their batch jobs in the AWS Cloud.